# preg_match get div content with class

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i have code like that

```
<div class="x-ic test"><div class="abc">Test</div><table>.......</table><p>....</p><div style="margin:5px;"></div></div>
```

i tried a few pattern but i didnt get result i want.

and i need to get result below

```
<div class="abc">Test</div><table>.......</table><p>....</p><div style="margin:5px;"></div>
```

Comment: Why regex? is this not in the DOM? How are you accessing that first string?

Comment: Which patterns did you try?

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) - I've written the code into functions in case you want to perform similar operations again:

```
function DOMinnerHTML(DOMNode $element)
{
    $innerHTML = "";
    $children = $element->childNodes;
    foreach ($children as $child)
    {
        $innerHTML .= $element->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);
    }
    return $innerHTML;
}
function getElContentsByTagClass($html,$tag,$class)
{
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html);//Turn the $html string into a DOM document
    $els = $doc->getElementsByTagName($tag); //Find the elements matching our tag name ("div" in this example)
    foreach($els as $el)
    {
        //for each element, get the class, and if it matches return it's contents
        $classAttr = $el->getAttribute("class");
        if(preg_match('#\b'.$class.'\b#',$classAttr) > 0) return DOMinnerHTML($el);
    }
}

//Calling it:
$html = '<div class="x-ic test"><div class="abc">Test</div><table>.......</table><p>....</p><div style="margin:5px;"></div></div>';

$ret = getElContentsByTagClass($html,'div','x-ic test');//<div class="abc">Test</div><table>.......</table><p>....</p><div style="margin:5px;"></div>
```

[PHP Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/c9s-apy) - Run (F9)

Comment: What a amazing function... you saved my day and one more thing this function may register in php standard library...

Comment: It works and vote up for this! However it has two tweaks to be applied. One, it produces warning for HTML5 tags like SECTION, HEADER, FOOTER. The good thing is that the warning can be suppressed by adding a @ in front of `$doc->loadHTML($html)` without losing the correct output. Second, since this function returns when a match is found inside foreach loop, matches should be stacked or concatenated before returning.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this with regex:

```
<?php 

$html = '<div class="x-ic test"><div class="abc">Test</div><table>.......</table><p>....</p><div style="margin:5px;"></div></div>';

$split = preg_replace('#^<div class="x-ic test">|</div>$#', '' , $html);

var_dump($split);

?>
```

Comment: OP: Note that this works only until that first tag becomes `<div class="x-ic test whatever">` or there's a line feed after that first tag, or any other changes to the HTML that are perfectly valid.

Comment: I say that not for your benefit, but for OP's.  Anyone asking about parsing HTML with regexes is probably not thinking ahead to the future.

Comment: You are right Andy best way to parse HTML is to use a HTML parser!

Answer (score 0):

The easy and adviced way to manipulate html is using DOM. I personally use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to do that.

But since i'm practicing REGEX, here's an answer using regex :) :

```
$text = '<div class="x-ic test"><div class="abc">Test</div><table>.......</table><p>....</p><div style="margin:5px;"></div></div>';

$text = preg_replace('/^(.*)(<div class="abc">.*)(<\/div>)$/', '$2', $text);

// OUTPUT:
<div class="abc">Test</div><table>.......</table><p>....</p><div style="margin:5px;"></div>
```

You can try it [HERE](http://codepad.org/WyyrwnXE)

Cheers :)

Comment: Your cutting off is unbalanced, I'd rather catch one `<div[^>]*>` in the first group, then have the `.*` in the middle.